# Eclipse Egit Project Explorer Changes

Tags: eclipse, git

I'm having an issue with `Eclipse` and `git` tracking changes. `Eclipse` doesn't show any changes unless I disconnect from `git` and reconnect.

**File Structure**

```
ProjectA  
  src
     backup.c
     compare.c
```

So let's say I make a change to `backup.c`. I expect `Eclipse` to add the `>` symbol to indicate changes. This doesn't happen.

- Refreshing the project does nothing.
- Right-click `backup.c` > Compare With > HEAD Revision shows the changes.
- On command line `git status` shows the `backup.c` as modified.

In order to try to fix this I tried to remove the project from `Eclipse` and then deleting the `.project` folder before creating a new project. No difference.

The following works and will add the `>` to indicate changes, however, it only refreshes once. If I make further changes to `compare.c` it does not show up and I again have to repeat the steps.

- Right-click project > Team > Disconnect
- Right-click project > Team > Share Project > Git

I'm out of ideas. How can I get `Eclipse` and `git` to work together? I'm running the latest version of `Eclipse` and `Egit`

**edit 1**

One thing I forgot to mention is the Synchronize view in Eclipe does show the changes. So Eclipse can see the change, it just doesn't mark it properly in Project Explorer.

**Text Decorations for Git (edit 2)**

- Files: {dirty:>} {name}
- Folders: {dirty:>} {name}
- Projects: {dirty:>} {name} [{repository }{branch}{ branch_status}]
- Submodules: {dirty:>} {name} [{branch}{ branch_status}]{ short_message}

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Label Decorations_, is _Git_ checked? Could you show a screenshot of _Window > Preferences: Team > Git > Label Decorations_, tab _Text Decorations_?

Comment: Yes, it's checked. That's why the decorations show up when I disconnect and reconnect. They just don't change. They are static until I disconnect/reconnect. `Files`: {dirty:>} {name}, `Folders`: {dirty:>} {name}, `Projects`: {dirty:>} {name} [{repository }{branch}{ branch_status}], `Submodules`: {dirty:>} {name} [{branch}{ branch_status}]{ short_message}